# Could not find PDO driver (PhpStorm and SQLite)

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, phpstorm, driver

I use PhpStorm to create a web page that saves data to a SQLite database. I have created tables in the DB, installed drivers in PhpStorm and it says, the connection is successful.

Ok, but when I try to open it in Chrome, it says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Users\maness\PhpstormProjects\icd0007\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\maness\PhpstormProjects\icd0007\index.php(4): PDO->__construct('jdbc:sqlite:db1...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\maness\PhpstormProjects\icd0007\index.php on line 4`

The code on line 4 within the index.php file is the following:

```
$connection = new PDO('jdbc:sqlite:db1.sqlite');
```

I have turned on every SQL extension in php.ini, tried different options - no result. Can you name the exact extensions needed to launch SQLite, or what am I doing wrong?

P.S. 
PhpStorm SQLite Xerial drivers. I use PHP from XAMPP folder.

Answer (score 2):

`jdbc` is not a valid [PDO driver](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php).

Since you want to connect to a SQLite database, remove `jdbc` from your dsn:

```
$connection = new PDO('sqlite:db1.sqlite');
```

You seem to have confused PhpStorm's SQLite connectivity with PHP's.